# Is it possible to install varnish cache and use it in localhost

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish

Is it possible to install **varnish cache** and use it in **localhost**. I'm using **xampp web server** to run magento in my localhost. I can able to get plenty of documents in online to configure varnish cache and use it in the server level. I would need to know that can we able to do it in localhost.

If yes, Shall I follow the steps which has given in **[devdocs.magento.com](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-configure.html)**?
or, if there is any other document in the online please share the link here. Or, please share the link if there is same kind of post available.

If no, please tell me that why cant we do that in localhost. So that I can be aware of it.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VarnishOnCygwinWindows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and you need to follow these steps: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-varnish-setup/

From here, you can install varnish cache in Magento store. You need to make some minimal changes in configuration as per store requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below links to achieve it:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-magento.html

Comment: Already I have mentioned that link in my post.